# how to display all the fields using the display method in the subclass and from superClass

Tags: java, inheritance, superclass, prototypal-inheritance, subclass

How to display all the fields using the display method in the subclass and from superClass,What i want is to display all the fields in the subclass from the superclass

Comment: By overriding toString method.

Comment: Can you explain a bit please

Comment: see the answer I provided

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Eclipse, the auto-generated toString can do that. 
Including the Override as Ali Alamiri mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to call the display method of the subclass from your superclass so that you can display the values of your subclass field.

If that's what you mean, then you first want to override the toString method in your subclass:

```
class Derived extends Base
{
   private String field1 = "Field";
   public String toString()
   {
      return "Field 1: " + field1; //etc
   }

}
```

then from your superclass, you want to have an object of your subclass, which you call the toString method on, so something like:

```
class Base
{
    private Derived derived;
    public Base()
    {
       derived = new Derived();
       System.out.println(derived.toString());
    }
}
```